# Go not resolving GitHub package imports

Tags: go, dependency-management, package-managers

New to Go/Golang and am trying to understand its package/dependency management system a little better.

I cloned [this simple web service repo](https://github.com/WPFerg/services) off GitHub and tried running it with `go run main.go`. In that `main.go` file:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/wpferg/services/httpHandlers"
    "github.com/wpferg/services/storage"
    "github.com/wpferg/services/structs"
)

const PORT = 8080

var messageId = 0

func createMessage(message string, sender string) structs.Message {
    messageId++
    return structs.Message{
        ID:      messageId,
        Sender:  sender,
        Message: message,
    }
}

func main() {
    log.Println("Creating dummy messages")

    storage.Add(createMessage("Testing", "1234"))
    storage.Add(createMessage("Testing Again", "5678"))
    storage.Add(createMessage("Testing A Third Time", "9012"))

    log.Println("Attempting to start HTTP Server.")

    http.HandleFunc("/", httpHandlers.HandleRequest)

    var err = http.ListenAndServe(":"+strconv.Itoa(PORT), nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln("Server failed starting. Error: %s", err)
    }
}
```

When I run this (`run go main.go`) I get:

```
main.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/wpferg/services/httpHandlers" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/wpferg/services/httpHandlers (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/wpferg/services/httpHandlers (from $GOPATH)
main.go:9:2: cannot find package "github.com/wpferg/services/storage" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/wpferg/services/storage (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/wpferg/services/storage (from $GOPATH)
main.go:10:2: cannot find package "github.com/wpferg/services/structs" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/wpferg/services/structs (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/wpferg/services/structs (from $GOPATH)
```

So it *seems* Go supports a way of "fetching" other packages from GitHub via HTTP but for some reason when I run it locally, its expecting the packages to be local.

What can I do to fix this so that the other packages are resolved? Why is Go looking for them locally instead of fetching them via the URL?

Comment: Pro tip: Do not run your Go code with `go run main.go`. If you think you cannot bear to type `go build` and rund the generated program you should use `go run` with a folder or package argument only. (Stay away from tutorials advising to use go run main.go.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that this repo is from pre [go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) era and doesn't use any dependency management system. Easiest way to fix it is to try to initialize it as module(if you use go < 1.14 set environment variable `GO111MODULE=on`):

```
go mod init github.com/wpferg/services
```

And then run:

```
go run main.go
```

it will resolve it's dependencies automatically and try to start the program.

P.S. But, regarding that it's an older code and it's unclear with what golang version(and packages versions) it was written it's likely that it will not work or, in some way, will be broken.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @Grigoriy (+1)! Quick followup question if you don't mind: I'm coming to Go from over a _decade_ of Java experience, where we have dependency management tools like Gradle, Maven, Ant, etc. that fetch 3rd party libraries from repositories. Is there anything similar in Go, and if so can you give me a 60,000 ft overview of what its called and how it works?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup: the best overview is the official documentation, [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), and the modules wiki page: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup Starting from go 1.11, go modules(check link in my answer) is a standard for dependency management. It comes [with `go` cmd](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules). Before that there was a bunch of external solutions like `glide`, `dep`, `vgo` -- but they all outdated now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, imports worked for a long time, then suddenly didn't.

I fixed it by running `go mod tidy` in the console.